# Is there way to make a pageBlock title a link?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is that possible to have a href inside the apex:pageBlock title?

I'm trying to do something like this but its not working:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Upload Link - {!'<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>'"} " />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the content to a header [apex:facet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_facet.htm). This lets you add HTML content that is placed in the containing element. The available facet names are documented towards the end of the [apex:pageBlock documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlock.htm).

Here is an example from one of our pages (for an `apex:pageBlockSection`):

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:facet name="header">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="inline">
            <h3>Payees (go to&nbsp;<apex:outputLink value="/apex/cve__Payees?id={!claim.Id}&psId={!ps.Id}">Payees</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;page)</h3>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:facet>
```

The `h3` is the same element that is emitted when you use the `title` attribute in an `apex:pageBlockSection`. Use your browser's Developer Tools Inspect feature to check the markup emitted for the `title` in your `apex:pageBlock` case.

**PS**

The HTML that apex:pageBlock injects is pretty messy so you need to add a lot of junk to get the same result (though you might be able to trim it down):

```
<apex:page>
    <!-- Not using facet -->
    <apex:pageBlock title="Page Block">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Page Block Section">
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <!-- Same styling using facets -->
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                <div class="pbHeader">
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="pbTitle">
                                <h2 class="mainTitle">Page Block <a href="#">link</a></h2>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                    <h3>Page Block Section <a href="#">link</a></h3>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks Keith but i'm trying to do that in pageBlock then pageBlockSection

Comment: @NickKahn I assume you can add a separate apex:facet to each and the facet will be rendered in the immediate container. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I did tried but did not come up the way I wanted, I will post the code in a minute.

Comment: here is what i have tried with pageBlock `<apex:pageBlock title="test" >
    <apex:facet name="header">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="inline">
            <h3>Payees (go to&nbsp;<apex:outputLink value="/apex/cve__Payees?id=">Payees</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;page)</h3>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:facet>
    </apex:pageBlock>`

Comment: @NickKahn I've added a PS that shows how to get styling that matches the non-facet case.